Signalr , porque no funciona con js
Hola tengo una duda tengo un ASP.NET core api web y tengo una duda esta es mi api con signal...
Hub:
    public class ChatHub:Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }

Program :
using SignalR_V1.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);



// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(options =>
{
    options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5500")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyOrigin();
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapHub<ProductsHub>("/productsHub");
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
app.Run();

Lo corri con dotnet run.
Por otro lado cree una carpeta aparte llamada chat_js con estos archivos :

Index.html :
<!-- chat.html -->
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Chat en tiempo real</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>Chat</h1>
     <div id="chat-container">
         <ul id="messages"></ul>
     </div>
     <input type="text" id="message-input" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje">
     <button id="send-button">Enviar</button>

     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/6.0.1/signalr.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>


Styles.css :
#chat-container {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 10px;
height: 300px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
#messages {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#messages li {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#message-input {
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
#send-button {
padding: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}

Script.js :
 const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
     .withUrl("http://localhost:5121/chathub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1")
     .build();

 console.log(connection)

 async function start() {
     try {
         await connection.start();
         console.log("SignalR Connected.");
     } catch (err) {
         console.log(err);
         setTimeout(start, 5000);
     }
 };

 connection.onclose(async () => {
     await start();
 });


 start();



Y este lo corro con liveserver me abre el http://localhost:5500,
En caso tal es que realizo la consulta y sale este error

No tengo claro si este script del html de donde estoy pidiendo la libreria signal sea el correcto o no
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/6.0.1/signalr.js"></script> 

Ya que si hago una peticion post si funciona:
const url = 'http://localhost:5121/chathub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1'; 

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    body: null 
};

fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Hubo un problema al realizar la solicitud: ' + response.status);
        }
        return response.json(); 
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Respuesta del servidor:', data);
        
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al realizar la solicitud:', error);
    });

Como puedo solucionar este error que me ocurre al momento de consultar, o alguna idea para intertar resolverlo gracias un saludo!

para solucionar el problema descubri que en script.js hay que poner
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("http://localhost:5121/chathub",{
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })  // Ajusta según la configuración de tu servidor .NET (6,7,8)
    .build();

En vez de solo esto:
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
     .withUrl("http://localhost:5121/chathub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1")
     .build();

skipNegotiation: true: Indica a SignalR que omita la fase de negociación automática y utilice la configuración proporcionada directamente.
transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets: Especifica que deseas utilizar WebSockets como el método de transporte para la comunicación bidireccional en tiempo real.
Y me asegure de tener el protocolo websokect activo

